# Python. Selenium. Upload file with no input tag

Tags: python, linux, selenium

Here's a drop zone HTML

```
<dropzone _ngcontent-c80="" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png" _nghost-c81="">
<div _ngcontent-c81="" class="content">
<div _ngcontent-c80="" class="drop-image-icon half-margin-bottom" iconid="drop-image" svg-icon="" vb="0 0 64 48" _nghost-c4="">
<svg _ngcontent-c4="" viewBox="0 0 64 48">
<use _ngcontent-c4="" xlink:href="https://core-stg1.teradek.com/app/kovalyovfortests/studio/assets#drop-image">
</use>
</svg>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c80="" class="primary">Drop an image here</div>
<div _ngcontent-c80="" class="primary half-margin-top half-margin-bottom">— or —</div>
<a _ngcontent-c80="" class="secondary">Select an image from your computer</a>
</div>
</dropzone>
```

I tried to send the file with

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@iconid="drop-image"]').send_keys('/home/user/pic/3-1.png')`

and get traceback:

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

How can I send the file into drop zone using .send_keys?

P.S. It works with

```
import pyautogui

find_by_xpath('//*[@iconid="drop-image"]').click()

pyautogui.write(/home/user/pic/3-1.png, interval=0.25)
pyautogui.press('return')
```

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative `sendkey` method, you can use `Action` class:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('...')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).send_keys('/home/user/pic/3-1.png').perform()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. The process completed without errors, but the file does not appears in the drop zone.

Comment: @Oladuwek What you mean `file does not appears in the drop zone` ?